# what is quality assurance?

Tags: manual-testing

What we are going to verify in quality assurance stage? & what we are not going to verify? like wise what are we going to check in quality control stage? what are we not going to test on quality control satge?

Answer (score 4):

**"A" stands for "Assistance"**. QA cannot "assure" quality - quality has to be build in into product by developers using processes, and QA provides info to management how these processes work, how improvements can be made, and what is quality status.

**Quality cannot be bought, but has to be paid for.** It means that quality is not a commodity anyone can just buy on the market as needed but has to be **build in** into your product during it's whole life cycle starting at design and project management, it cannot be slapped on the end before release by more testing.

To release or not to release (with currently known detected bugs, and possible unknown bugs) is business decision. Releasing crappy product might you lose future customers. Flawless product released 2 years too late means bankrupt company.

Comment: Peter, I hope you see this comment. Your phrase "Quality cannot be bought, but has to be paid for" seems to be an original one from yourself, is it?

Comment: When I do a quoted search for that phrase, the only results that come up are ones you made. I think its quite interesting depending on where the quality is bought (or attempted), early on is the only place that works as you go on to explain. I really like it and will be using this phrase in talks and slides (credit will be given to you). Thanks!

Comment: I heard it originally with "Excellence cannot be bought" at a commencement address in Uni of Rochester 2013 and modified it to my needs :-) Google search attributes "excellence..." variant to Nobel laureate Val Fitch. You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The terms can be confusing because of how they are normally used in the software business, where "QA" is typically synonymous with testing.

*Quality control* is a statistical process.  In manufacturing, quality control might mean testing samples of the product as they come off the assembly line.  Software is not a manufacturing process, and quality control doesn't make a lot of sense in software.  (In particular, it does *not* mean testing some bug fixes but not others.)

*Quality assurance* is a set of processes designed to promote quality.  For example, you could argue that using a change management system, a bug tracking system, requirements documents, and a test plan are all part of quality assurance.  In software, testing is part of quality assurance, but quality assurance includes other things too.

Answer (score 1):

There are no separate stage for QA. It is an activity of process and product quality improvement and QC it is a stage of checking and reporting about current quality level. 
[image]